# What money is used on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, money, tatooine

If Republic credits are no good, what is used for or what is money called on Tatooine? Water would be an obvious currency but some form of 'cash' is seen being used.

Comment: I have voted to close this question based on our [Broadest are targets for the specific](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/are-multiple-variations-of-a-question-with-subtle-distinctions-duplicate) duplicate policy, as the answer in the linked question specifically addresses this question, and the question is a broader version of this question.

Answer (score 1):

### Peggats, truguts, and wupiupi.

From the [Star Wars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Peggat), cited to *Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*:

> A peggat was a form of currency used by the Hutts on Tatooine. A peggat was the equivalent of four truguts or 64 golden wupiupi, while it normally exchanged for roughly 40 credits.

[Peggats](https://web.archive.org/web/20100210030930/http://starwars.com/databank/character/benquadinaros/index.html) and [truguts](https://web.archive.org/web/20110517074826/http://www.starwars.com:80/databank/character/elanmak/index.html) used to be mentioned in the (canon) Star Wars Databank, but it seems they aren't any more. [Wupiupi](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=q_7GcsVs83UC&dq=%22wupiupi%22+phantom+menace&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=wupiupi) are mentioned in the Phantom Menace Visual Dictionary.

Comment: looking like this Q is being closed down, do you want to check out the 'original question' before I delete?

Comment: Truguts are also used in the PS1 game the Phantom Menace

Comment: @Seamusthedog What do you mean by "original question"?

Comment: @Randal'Thor see the yellow box above my question, original maybe wrong word mine being a dupe

Comment: @Seamusthedog Ahh, I see. Well, it looks like the original question is already satisfactorily answered, so I don't need to repost there. Also, [there's no need to delete your question just because it's a dupe](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7944/31394) :-)